# Get country id's from country list on suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a script that needs to update a record due to his country.
so I have to make a save search and add a country filter - the problem is that I have the country code or country name but not the country id - the save search need to have the country id

```
var search_htsCodes = search.create({
                    type: "customrecordau_test_codes",
                    filters: [
                        ["custrecord_au_part_number.internalidnumber", "equalto", item],
                        "AND",
                        ["custrecord_au_country", "anyof", country] // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                    ],
                    columns: [
                        search.createColumn({
                            name: "internalid",
                            label: "ID"
                        })
                    ]
                });
```

Filter expecting numeric value was removed, as non-numeric value 'Estonia' was provided

Any idea how to get this work?

Comment: In filter section, instead of "custrecord_au_country" you can use other fields like Country name or code, based on the data you have.

Comment: There is no fields of country name or code there

Answer (score 0):

You can try using help id: 63281, 82791

.>Get Country IDs and Country Names on SuiteScript
.>Use SuiteScript to Generate a List/File of All Country and State Names/Abbreviations